# How can i set Offset to specific value

Tags: flutter, dart

i have found this simple full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Exp3();
  }
}

typedef OffsetBuilder = Offset Function(Size size);

class Exp3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Exp3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Exp3> createState() => _Exp3State();
}

class _Exp3State extends State<Exp3> {

  OffsetBuilder _offsetBuilder = (_) => Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return Container( // parent container
          color: Colors.red,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              final currentBuilder = _offsetBuilder;
              _offsetBuilder = (Size containerSize) {
                return currentBuilder.call(containerSize) + details.delta;
              };
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: CustomSingleChildLayout(
              delegate: MyCustomSingleChildLayoutDelegate(
                canGoOffParentBounds: false,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                offsetBuilder: _offsetBuilder,
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now my widget located at Offset.zero; for first snapshot by it's variable `OffsetBuilder _offsetBuilder = (_) => Offset.zero;`

**Question**: How i set `OffsetBuilder _offsetBuilder = (_) => Offset.zero;` to located at following value by first snapshot or first initialize

```
 last point on the screen (max buttom) - 300
```

and here the class i use for `SingleChildLayoutDelegate`

```
 class MyCustomSingleChildLayoutDelegate extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
      final Offset Function(Size childSize) offsetBuilder;
      final EdgeInsets padding;
      final bool canGoOffParentBounds;
    
      MyCustomSingleChildLayoutDelegate({
        required this.offsetBuilder,
        required this.padding,
        required this.canGoOffParentBounds,
      });
    
      @override
      BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return BoxConstraints.loose(constraints.biggest).deflate(padding);
      }
    
      @override
      Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
        Offset childTopLeft = offsetBuilder.call(childSize);
    
        if (canGoOffParentBounds) {
          // no more checks on the position needed
          return childTopLeft;
        }
    
        if (childTopLeft.dx + childSize.width > size.width - padding.right) {
          final distance = -(childTopLeft.dx - (size.width - padding.right - childSize.width));
          childTopLeft = childTopLeft.translate(distance, 0);
        }
        if (childTopLeft.dx < padding.left) {
          final distance = padding.left - childTopLeft.dx;
          childTopLeft = childTopLeft.translate(distance, 0);
        }
        if (childTopLeft.dy + childSize.height > size.height - padding.bottom) {
          final distance = -(childTopLeft.dy - (size.height - padding.bottom - childSize.height));
          childTopLeft = childTopLeft.translate(0, distance);
        }
        if (childTopLeft.dy < padding.top) {
          final distance = padding.top - childTopLeft.dy;
          childTopLeft = childTopLeft.translate(0, distance);
        }
        return childTopLeft;
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldRelayout(MyCustomSingleChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
        return oldDelegate.offsetBuilder != offsetBuilder;
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73858566/2252830 and change `ValueNotifier(Offset.zero)` to any offset you like

Comment: i tried to use alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter but it still topLeft .. i need the widget located on like bottomCenter - 300  .. How could i set Offset from being Offset.zero to bottomCenter - 300 for first inislize

Comment: we have this var offset = Offset.zero; so how could i chnage  = Offset.zero to = bottomCenter - 300