# How to center a widget inside a stack and moving it programmatically?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a widget in a stack that should be centered in the stack initially. The user should be able to move the widget programmatically in the stack.

I have tried a number of things. I can center the widget by setting the alignment of Stack to center using `alignment: Alignment.center` of the stack. And if the no TRBL properties of the Positioned widget is not set, then the widget is centered. But Then how do you move the widget from center to 2 pixels above center or 5 pixel right?

```
  Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
        Positioned(
          child:Container(
             height: 50,
             width: 50,
             child: Text('Move this programmatically')
           )
         )
       ]
    )
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853825/how-to-prevent-widget-from-passing-out-of-screen-border#73858566

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this widget. I am using `LayoutBuilder`.

```dart
class StackAMovement extends StatefulWidget {
  const StackAMovement({super.key});

  @override
  State<StackAMovement> createState() => _StackAMovementState();
}

class _StackAMovementState extends State<StackAMovement> {
  double shiftX = 0;
  double shiftY = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          shiftY += 2;
          shiftX += 5;
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (p0, constraints) {
          final centerW = constraints.maxWidth / 2;
          final centerH = constraints.maxHeight / 2;
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                  left: centerW + shiftX -25,//-25 half of container width
                  top: centerH + shiftY -25,//-25 half of container height
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.purple,
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      child: Text('Move this programmatically')))
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not really, the initial position is not centered, for that you would need to know the child size,  for example `CustomSingleChildLayout` can give you this, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853825/how-to-prevent-widget-from-passing-out-of-screen-border#73858566 on how you could use it

Comment: Thanks, I've forgot about this. Btw we can subtract the half size from this while width and height is hard-coded on Container

Comment: and what if it's not hardcoded?  or container is wrapped with some not fixed size decoration?

Comment: Then we need to get the child size as you've mentioned.

Comment: btw, notice how `CustomSingleChildLayout` allows to relayout its child without rebuilding widget tree (no `setState` used)

Comment: Wow, thanks, I've saved the post and will check after finishing my HW.

Comment: Why are you using such a difficult path?
My answer is completely correct and I use it all the time.
I wrap the widget that I want to drag to a certain position in the Stack with Positioned.fill so that it covers the entire Stack area from the beginning, and then wrap it with Align and place it in the area I want to drag within this entire area.
Why would I ever calculate the centerline of a widget when it's that simple?

Answer (score -1):

```
    Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              child:Center(
               child:Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: 50,
                 child: Text('Move this programmatically')
               ))
             )
           ]
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this. very easy:

```
      Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
            Positioned(
              left:1,
              right:1,
              child:Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: 50,
                 child: Text('Move this programmatically')
               )
             )
           ]
        )
```