# get parent size (area boundary) in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am learning Flutter and I wanted to create a simple example with three colored squares which I can move/drag with a mouse inside a window. I however want the movement of the squares to be limited by the area of the window. I managed to set the limitation for the lower boundary of the position (simply it cannot be smaller than zero) but **I did not manage to find a way to limit the upper boundary.** I would need somehow to get the size (width and heigth) of the parent widget. But I did not find any way to get it.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Moving Boxes',
      home: MyMainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyMainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyMainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          MovableBox(color: Colors.red, left: 100, top: 100),
          MovableBox(color: Colors.yellow, left: 200, top: 50),
          MovableBox(color: Colors.blue, left: 0, top: 0)
          ]
    ));
  }
}

class MovableBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const MovableBox({super.key, required this.color, this.top = 0, this.left = 0});

  @override
  State<MovableBox> createState() => _MovableBoxState();

  final Color color;
  final double top;
  final double left;
}

class _MovableBoxState extends State<MovableBox> {
  double _left = 0;
  double _top = 0;

  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    _left = widget.left;
    _top = widget.top;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top:  max(_top, 0), // here I limit the lower boundary but I would also like to limit the upper one
      left: max(_left, 0),
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      child: Container(
        color: widget.color,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            setState(() {
              _left += details.delta.dx;
              _top += details.delta.dy;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I know that there is a class called `Draggable` which is supposed to do something like this. But for learning purposes I wanted to implement this from lower-level components.

I guess that my design is probably wrong. Maybe there are several ways to achieve this. I would like to learn as many of them as possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853825/how-to-prevent-widget-from-passing-out-of-screen-border#73858566

Comment: @pskink Thank you, you are right that question describes situation very similar to mine... But OMG! Is the solution of this trivial problem really so complicated in Flutter? I am coming from Qt framework and there everything is so simple and easy to achieve (but the future seems rather grim for Qt). Flutter feels as a total opposite... I do not understand how such a messy framework with totally unreadable code became so popular.

Comment: it's not complicated at all: just one delegate class for positioning your child where all the sizes are combined: parent size and child size, if you remove optional `final Alignment alignment; final EdgeInsets padding` it's gonna be just 5 lines of not trivial, boilerplate code (i mean you need to override `getPositionForChild` returning valid `Offset`)

Comment: @pskink Thanks for 'heads up'. Maybe it is just the fact that I am still a complete noob in Flutter. The mixture of imperative and declarative style does not make sense when I look it at. But I really want to learn it so I will give it a try. (and it will probably require unlearning the Qt ways)

Comment: btw I was big fan of `Qt` in the past but I'm pretty sure the success of react / flutter had some solid reasons

Comment: and `MediaQuery.of(context)` is not a way to follow as it gives you the size of the whole screen - while in most cases your view is a subset of it (you could use rather `LayoutBuilder` in such case)

Comment: i totally forgot about one small widget I wrote last month: https://gist.github.com/pskink/10c8fd372113f0b36570db96d58d818e#file-flow_stack-dart-L21 - it gives you a possibility of placing your children depending on child and parent sizes, check the most generic constructor `FlowStackEntry.fromCallbacks`

Comment: @pskink Thank you, I will check that code and will try to learn from it.