# Positioned widget with GestureDetector, Dragging a widget will go off the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, gesturedetector, flutter-positioned

Im trying to Drag a container with `GestureDetector`, but when i dragg to the edges of the screen the container is going off the screen.

***I wanted it to stop when it reaches the edges of the screen.***

[image]

Here is the example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawDraggableRectangle extends StatefulWidget {
  const DrawDraggableRectangle({super.key});

  @override
  State<DrawDraggableRectangle> createState() => _DrawDraggableRectangleState();
}

class _DrawDraggableRectangleState extends State<DrawDraggableRectangle> {
  double zoneHeight = 122;
  double zoneWidth = 112;
  double topY = 21;
  double leftX = 16;
  late double initX;
  late double initY;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: topY,
          left: leftX,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onPanStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
              setState(() {
                initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
                initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
              });
            },
            onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
              final dx = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
              final dy = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;
              initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
              initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
              setState(() {
                topY = topY + dy;
                leftX = leftX + dx;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              height: zoneHeight,
              width: zoneWidth,
              //color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.pink, // Set border color
                    width:
                        3.0), // Set border width// Make rounded corner of border
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853825/how-to-prevent-widget-from-passing-out-of-screen-border#73858566

Answer (score 1):

You can try to `clamp()` the values assigned to y and x to the boundaries of your screen. In the example below I used `double.infinity` for the upper value as we don't know exact size of the screen at this time.

```dart
            onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
              final dx = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
              final dy = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;
              initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
              initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
              setState(() {
                topY = (topY + dy).clamp(0.0, double.infinity);
                leftX = (leftX + dx).clamp(0.0, double.infinity);
              });
            },
```

See this in practice using [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=58ff82fc9009d08284d36a1ea9590d69)

If you'd like to make sure that the `Positioned` stays within arbitrary bounds you may try to use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) around `Stack` to get the constraints. Then you would be able to clamp the right and bottom edge in a similar way.

Comment: It works, But on the bottom & on the right still goes off the screen.
will try the LayoutBuilder

Comment: @Dominik Roszkowski can you post an example for LayoutBuilder, or modify the above code itself in that?