# I am using draggable items in a stack but items are moving outside the stack content

Tags: flutter

The item is not bounded to the image on the stack instead it going outside if i am dragging it

i try to wrap the stack into sized box but it is not working for me

```
    return SizedBox(
      height: widget.h,
      width: widget.w,

      child: GestureDetector(

        onTap: () {
          // Deselect the currently selected text item
          ref.watch(textItemContainerWrappedProvider(screenid).notifier).state =
              false;
          setState(() {
            _selectedTextItemIndex = null;
          });
        },
        child: Center(
          
          child: Stack(
          
            children: [
              Image.network(
                widget.image,
                height: widget.h,
                width: widget.w,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
              for (int i = 0; i < widget.textItems.length; i++)
                Textitem(
                  textItem: widget.textItems[i],
                  h: widget.h,
                  w: widget.w,
                  isContainerWrapped: _selectedTextItemIndex == i,
                  
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: check [How to prevent widget from passing out of screen border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853825/how-to-prevent-widget-from-passing-out-of-screen-border#73858566)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the stack to only consider the image when sizing itself, you should wrap all the other children in `Positioned`:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Image.network(
      // ...
    ),
    for (final item in widget.textItems)
      // Use other constructors+argmuments to Positioned and/or
      // alignment widgets within Positioned.fill to get the
      // exact alignment you need.
      Positioned.fill(
        Textitem(
          // ...
        ),
      ),
  ],
),
```

Relevant excerpt from the [Stack docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html):

> Each child of a Stack widget is either positioned or non-positioned. Positioned children are those wrapped in a Positioned widget that has at least one non-null property. The stack sizes itself to contain all the non-positioned children, which are positioned according to alignment.

You might also want to consider moving the Stack into the [`framebuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/frameBuilder.html) of your Image so that it is only rendered after the rendered width and height are known.